# Pycharm - JSX, How to surround style classes, id's in whole file with curly braces '{}'?

Tags: pycharm, code-formatting

I am using Pycharm and i am curious, how to surround style classes in a file with curly braces - {}. So, I am trying to learn some **React**, and yesterday i did it, but i do not remember how i did it, because i tried to just reformat code indentation and in the process i did something like this in the pictures below somehow with key-shortcut or with **Options** Probably in **Code**

Basically, what i mean by that is how to change code like this:

```jsx
<ul className='navbar-nav nav-fill w-100'>
    <li className='nav-item'>item1</li>
    <li className='nav-item'>item2</li>
    <li className='nav-item'>item3</li>
    <li className='nav-item'>item4</li>
    <li className='nav-item'>item5</li>
</ul>
```

to look like this:

```jsx
<ul className={ 'navbar-nav nav-fill w-100' }>
    <li className={ 'nav-item' }>item1</li>
    <li className={ 'nav-item' }>item2</li>
    <li className={ 'nav-item' }>item3</li>
    <li className={ 'nav-item' }>item4</li>
    <li className={ 'nav-item' }>item5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to know if there is any key shortcut like: **Ctrl + something** or any **Option** to reformat code, because it will be too much work to do it line by line manually with **'Shift + {'**. I know this is optional, and it does not change how the code works, but it looks cleaner for me.